# AIX: Move file into a year month folder structure using date of file

Tags: date, for-loop, awk, aix

I am trying to create a folder structure for audit logs that gets generated by the AIX system and Database

Below is a simple example of a file in a folder:

```
ls -l /opt/audit/move/
```

Output:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 gl_user  user      0 18 Aug 2019  test1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 gl_user  user      0 06 Nov 18:55 test2.txt
```

The problem with the above ls -l command is that recent files in column 8 displays time instead of the year. I could of used awk and a for loop to get the month and year for the file, but this is not an option as seen above

The idea is to move the files in the below folder structure:

```
# ls -l /opt/audit/2019/August/test1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 gl_user  user      0 18 Aug 2019  test1.txt

# ls -l /opt/audit/2022/November/test2.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 gl_user  user      0 06 Nov 18:55 test2.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed can be used as a replacement for the the above case statement:

```
FILE_MONTH=`istat $i | grep -w "Last modified:" | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/Jan/January/g' | sed 's/Feb/February/g' | sed 's/Mar/March/g' | sed 's/Apr/April/g' | sed 's/Jun/June/g' | sed 's/Jul/July/g' | sed 's/Aug/August/g' | sed 's/Sep/September/g' | sed 's/Oct/October/g' | sed 's/Nov/November/g' | sed 's/Dec/December/g'`
```

Below is the full stack:

```
INFORLOG_BKP="/opt/audit"
for i in `ls ${INFORLOG_BKP}/move`
do
FILE_MONTH=`istat $i | grep -w "Last modified:" | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/Jan/January/g' | sed 's/Feb/February/g' | sed 's/Mar/March/g' | sed 's/Apr/April/g' | sed 's/Jun/June/g' | sed 's/Jul/July/g' | sed 's/Aug/August/g' | sed 's/Sep/September/g' | sed 's/Oct/October/g' | sed 's/Nov/November/g' | sed 's/Dec/December/g'`
FILE_YEAR=`istat ${INFORLOG_BKP}/move/$i | grep -w "Last modified:" | awk '{print $6}'`

#
# Create directory if it does not exist
#
[ -d ${INFORLOG_BKP}/${FILE_YEAR}/${MONTH_STRING}/ ] || mkdir -p ${INFORLOG_BKP}/${FILE_YEAR}/${        MONTH_STRING}/

mv ${INFORLOG_BKP}/move/$i ${INFORLOG_BKP}/${FILE_YEAR}/${MONTH_STRING}/

done
```

Comment: for each pass through your loop you're going to spawn 18 subprocesses (each `$(command ...)` is a subprocess, each pipe invokes a subprocess); spawning subprocesses is *expensive* in terms of memory, cpu and overall time; if you're going to spend all that coding on a dozen `sed` calls you might as well pull the `sed` (and `grep`) calls into the `awk` script ... accomplish the same thing and eliminate 14 subprocess calls at the same time

Comment: at a minimum eliminate 11 subprocess calls by consolidating the 12x `sed` callls into a single call, eg: `sed 's/Jan/January/g; s/Feb/February/g; s/Mar/March/g; ... s/Dec/December/g'`

Comment: That is a good point

Answer (score 2):

One idea using `ksh93` (for associative array support):

```
typeset -A months=( [Jan]="January" [Feb]="February" )   # OP can fill in the rest of the array

for fname in "${INFORLOG_BKP}"/move/*
do
    read -r mon3 year < <(istat "${fname}" | awk '/Last modified:/{print $5,$6}')
    tgtdir="${INFORLOG_BKP}/${year}/${months[$mon3]}"
    mkdir -p "${tgtdir}"                                 # '-p' also says to *not* print an error msg if dir already exists
    mv "${fname}" "${tgtdir}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This method involves using istat with a for loop to get the month and year of the file from the last modified date. This does work, but I would like to know if there is a better or shorter method to achieving what I want:

```
INFORLOG_BKP="/opt/audit"
for i in `ls ${INFORLOG_BKP}/move`
do
FILE_MONTH=`istat ${INFORLOG_BKP}/move/$i | grep -w "Last modified:" | awk '{print $5}'`
FILE_YEAR=`istat ${INFORLOG_BKP}/move/$i | grep -w "Last modified:" | awk '{print $6}'`

case $FILE_MONTH
in
        Jan)      MONTH_STRING=January
                ;;
        Feb)      MONTH_STRING=February
                ;;
        Mar)      MONTH_STRING=March
                ;;
        Apr)      MONTH_STRING=April
                ;;
        May)      MONTH_STRING=May
                ;;
        Jun)      MONTH_STRING=June
                ;;
        Jul)      MONTH_STRING=July
                ;;
        Aug)      MONTH_STRING=August
                ;;
        Sep)      MONTH_STRING=September
                ;;
        Oct)      MONTH_STRING=October
                ;;
        Nov)      MONTH_STRING=November
                ;;
        Dec)      MONTH_STRING=December
                ;;
esac

#
# Create directory if it does not exist
#
[ -d ${INFORLOG_BKP}/${FILE_YEAR}/${MONTH_STRING}/ ] || mkdir -p ${INFORLOG_BKP}/${FILE_YEAR}/${    MONTH_STRING}/

mv ${INFORLOG_BKP}/move/$i ${INFORLOG_BKP}/${FILE_YEAR}/${MONTH_STRING}/

done
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about. See also [orrect-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization).